# split one html table into two separate side-by-side blocks

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a form which consists of a table. The table is generated with an iterator over a java collection. The elements which are generated on each iteration are:

```
    <tr>
      <th>Element name</th>
      <td>Element value</td>
    </tr>
```

The table and /table tags are outside the iterator obviously.
The problem is that I need to have the table in two columns, in some cases.
Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/S32p2/

1. Is it possible to achieve this without the use of nested tables?

What makes it complicated for me, is that sometimes there are no fields at all, sometimes there should be one column and sometimes there should be two, based on the elements which are iterated over.

Also I am aware of this question: [How to have one html table split into two sections, side by side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001803/how-to-have-one-html-table-split-into-two-sections-side-by-side)

The problem is that I don't want the columns to be based on some predetermined length, but the second column should be made based on the values iterated over, as already mentioned earlier.

Comment: You're going to have to explain a bit more as to when the table should be one column and when it should be two. Are you looking for the [**colspan attribute?**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

Comment: basically:
       <iterator value="#values">
<if test="fieldKey == foo">
first column
</if>
<elseif test="fieldKey == bar">
second column
</elseif>