# Duplicate <thead> across columns

Tags: html, css

Quite simple really. I've probably missed something obvious but here goes.

I have a `<table>` inside a multi-column view. The idea being, it's a fairly tall table so having it on multiple columns makes it less obnoxiously vertical and fits better on-screen.

The problem is that the rows in columns 2 and beyond have no header.

If I go to Print Preview, however, each column has a "copy" of the `<thead>` - as it should, IMO, since that's what the `<thead>` is for.

Is it possible to get this behaviour, apparently only available by default in `@media print`, to work on the webpage itself?

(Note that the table's contents are dynamic and the whole thing should be responsive, so manually inserting / breaking up the table is a no-go.)

```css
#container {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Demo added. You're right, that was stupid of me not to include!

Comment: I don't see it happening without scripting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeating table header when splitting via column-count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662576/repeating-table-header-when-splitting-via-column-count)

Comment: @ChrisW. Nice find. Has anything changed since 2015 or am I stuck with hacks?

Comment: I think the issue with this is accessibility. You'd want to hide the duplicated elements with `aria-hidden`.

Comment: Maybe just apply local scroll or pagination.